# Getting error when testing spring rest async controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

**Controller**

```java
    @PostMapping("/endpoint/group/move")
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<List<Endpoint>>> moveEndpointGroup(@RequestBody List<String> EndpointIds,
            @RequestParam("from") String fromGroupId, @RequestParam("to") String toGroupId)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException, ExecutionException {
        DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<List<Endpoint>>> result = new DeferredResult<>();
        if (EndpointIds != null && !EndpointIds.isEmpty()) {
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> EndpointService.moveEndpoints(EndpointIds, fromGroupId, toGroupId), executor)
                    .whenComplete((movedEndpointsList, ex) -> {
                        if (ex != null) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                        if (movedEndpointsList.size() == EndpointIds.size()) {
                            result.setResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(movedEndpointsList));
                        } else {
                            result.setResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT).body(movedEndpointsList));
                        }
                    });
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I have written the following test method, it's not working. When I run this test I am getting Async result for handler was not set during the specified timeToWait.

Can someone help me where I am doing wrong?

```java
    @Test
    public void testMoveEndpointGroup_WhenSuccess() throws Exception {

        List<Endpoint> EndpointList = Arrays.asList(Endpoint, Endpoint);

        List<String> EndpointIds = Arrays.asList("123");

        Mockito.when(EndpointService.moveEndpoints(Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))
                .thenReturn(EndpointList);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/endpoint/group/move")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(EndpointIds)).param("from", "gorupA").param("to", "groupB");

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.asyncDispatch(result)).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print()).andReturn();


        JsonNode actual = objectMapper.readTree(result.getResponse().getContentAsString()).get("content");

        String expected = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(Arrays.asList(EndpointList));

        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual.toString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You have the controller with url

```
@PostMapping("/endpoint/group/move")
```

But in the test you send a request to '/Endpoint**s**/group/move' (extra s)

```
post("/Endpoints/group/move")
```

2) And you don't need to '.get("content")' since you have alredy parsed the reponse body. Also looks like you don't need to parse the answer to JsonNode, just use a String

```
String actual = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
String expected = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(Arrays.asList(EndpointList));
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual.toString());
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when i run the test "Async result for handler was not set during the specified timeToWait=10000"

Comment: Did you debug the code and check that a result is really set to DefferedResult in controller during the test? What executor do you use for ComplitableFuture?

Comment: can you please explain what you are asking

Comment: I mean are you shure that one of 
`result.setResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(movedEndpointsList));`
or
`result.setResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT).body(movedEndpointsList));` is realy executed? According to your error message it looks like there is no response from controller in test. I have written the same controller and test and have the same mesage only if exception from CompletableFuture is thrown and  `throw new RuntimeException(ex); ` is executed. If you can share the full code, it will be very helpfull.